# Two-Level Threading Model

Tags: operating-systems, threads

In multithreading models, we have a two-level model in which we multiplexes many user-level threads to a smaller or equal number of kernel threads but also allows a user-level thread to be bound to a kernel thread.

[image]

Why we need such a model ? Can someone give an example where we need to use this model?

Answer (score 1):

In modern systems, we typically don't need this, because OS kernels provide adequate support for threads so that there can be a one-to-one mapping between user threads and kernel threads.

In some past systems, OS kernels didn't have support for creating multiple threads in a single process, or creating a new kernel thread was very expensive (slow).  Therefore, the only way to provide threads with good performance was to multiplex multiple user-level threads, all running within a single kernel thread.  This is no longer necessary in most modern OS's, under normal situations.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39185134/781723, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)